# ODBC issue: Unresolved symbol: SQLDriverConnect (code)

Tags: c, odbc, informix

I normally connect with SQLConnect but I am trying to resolve a problem I have encountered, so, I was trying to use SQLDriverConnect but I am getting the runtime error:

```
Unresolved symbol: SQLDriverConnect (code)
```

I do see this function in the ODBC library with a symbol of 'T', so I am not sure what would be causing this.

The application is running on Linux RedHat 7, the DBMS is Informix.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you wrote 'the my ODBC library', I'm not sure whether you meant 'my ODBC library' or 'the MyODBC library'; I fixed it one way, but you should fix it the other if need be. You should identify which platform you're working on; I suspect Linux or another Unix variant, but it would help to be sure. You say this is a runtime error, so the program links OK but when you run it, you get this error? It would help to have the list of shared libraries loaded by your program (`ldd your-program` or `otool -L your-program` or something similar). Which version of Informix ODBC (ClientSDK) do you have?

Comment: Thank you for the extra information you have supplied (and for clarifying the ODBC library).  Please show the code for an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) — it should not be very long at all — that reproduces the problem, and show the compilation commands, and the output of `ldd` on the executable.  It would still be helpful to know which version of the ClientSDK you are using, though it likely isn't going to be a controlling factor.  The output from `nm -g -o the-library.so | grep SQLDriverConnect` might be useful too.

Comment: When I changed from the static version of the odbc library (provided by the vendor) to the shared library verion, SQLDriverConnect was found and it worked.  This still doesn't expalin why the static version shows SQLDriverConnect in the symbols table with the 'T' symbol but yet, I get the unresolved error at runtime.